# Why Json.Net Deserializes enum value as integer and accepts as valid?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, enums, json.net

I am confused about how Json.NET serializes/deserializes enums.

I have this field in my JSON Schema:

```
"MyEnumValue": {
    "type": "string",
    "enum": ["D", "F", "R"]
},
```

and this C# code:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "MyEnumValue", Required = Required.Always)]
public MyEnumValue MyEnumValue { get; set; } 

public enum MyEnumValue 
{
    D, F, R
}
```

When I use this function:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject
```

The created Json text contains this:

```
"MyEnumValue":82
```

So JSON.NET deserializes an enum value that expects char as an integer which is an ASCII value of a char.

My questions are:
* Why don't I get the char only by Serializing?

- Is it normal for (Universal) JSON Schema rules?

Comment: I must be missing something here - your enum is defined as a series of integers. Why do you think that you should get a `char` by deserializing?

Comment: This question is confusing. `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` would convert a JSON string to an object not produce JSON so it would not create `"MyEnumValue": 82`. You did not explicitly set the value of your `MyEnumValue` so they will be implicitly assigned values 0 through 2 - they would never be serialized as 82 by default.

Comment: `(MyEnumValue)'R' == 82`

Comment: I think you may be abusing the enum feature. Are you assigning `MyEnumValue` in the way that @MatthewWhited is showing in an attempt to force your enum to be serialized as a string?

Comment: I was pointing out the problem he ran into not making a suggestion on how to fix his issue.

Comment: @MatthewWhited I was not suggesting that you were suggesting that was a solution. I am asking the OP to confirm if that is what they were doing.

Answer (score 8):

If you need to [de]serialize the enum as string, add this to the property:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Enum", Required = Required.Always)]
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public MyEnumValue MyEnumValue { get; set; }
```

Comment: No.. it doesn't work. Json accepts invalid values as well.. try it.

Comment: @Revious Json.net will just attempt to convert as best as it can. If you need to prevent invalid value like `{Enum: 312}, {Enum: invalid_value}` or `(MyEnumValue)312`, you need to validate them: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonSchema.htm